# Generating function of integer partitions at most m parts

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

The generating function of partition integer with the maximum number is m is $$
\frac{x^m}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^m)}
$$
It's quite easy to understand if you expand it $$
(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)\cdots(x^m+x^{2m}+\cdots)
$$
Because m is the maximum number, you partition must contain at least one m, as for the other number less than m, you can choose 0,1,2...
As the question turn to partition an integer into at most m parts, the generating function is $$
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^m)}
$$
I can't have an intuition.

Comment: Can you give us a bit of context here? What do you know? Where did you encounter this identity? Do you just want some intuition, or do you want a full proof (in which case, you should show some of your own work first)?

Comment: There is a bijection between "partitions with $\le m$ parts" and "partitions whose largest part is $\le m$", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421715/proof-the-number-of-partitions-of-n-into-at-most-m-parts-is-the-number-of-part). With the latter interpretation it is easy to arrive at the generating function using similar reasoning that you have given above.

Comment: Think about what happens to the statistics you mentioned when you take conjugate partitions.